# Javascript value changes outside jquery.post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a weired bug that is driving me crazy for some time now. I have the following piece of code:

```
function isLoggedIn() {

    var loggedIn = false;

    var requestData = {
        action: 'explore-webdesign-is-loggedin',
        request_url: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname,
        async: false,
        data: null
    };
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, requestData, function(data) {

        var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
        if (dataObj.success === true) {
            loggedIn = true;       
            alert("1.) " + loggedIn);
        }
    });    
    alert("2.) " + loggedIn);
    return loggedIn; 
};
```

Javascript spitts out both alerts, which is fine, however the first one says '1.) true' while the second one gives me '2.) false'. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX requests are **asynchronous** - your final alert is being executed while the AJAX is in progress - the first alert finishes once the AJAX is done (hence why it's in the callback).

You don't `return` from an async method like you are trying to do, instead you would pass a callback function in to be executed once the AJAX is done:

```
function isLoggedIn(callback) {
     ...
     ...
     jQuery.post(ajaxurl, requestData, function(data) {
         ...
         ...
         if (dataObj.success === true) {
             loggedIn = true;       
             callback(loggedIn);
         }
     });
}
```

Then call like so:

```
isLoggedIn(function(data) {
    if (data) //user is logged in
});
```

Comment: Nice one! Of course that's it. Ill redesign the function to take a callback as param. Will signal this as correct once I am allowed

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Cheers to you.

Comment: @JohnSmith -- Happy to help, callbacks are glorious once ya get them going right